# 422 Unprocessable Entity in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to implement upload a file functionality in my ror website. The file is uploaded by drag and drop on a div

I can access the file info using

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0].name
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0].size
```

and for uploading the file

```
upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]);

function upload(myfile) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("name", myfile.name);
        fd.append("fileToUpload", myfile);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "upload_main_file");
        xhr.send(fd);
}
```

controller code is

```
  def upload_main_file
    render :text => params[:name]
  end
```

Route is

```
post 'upload_material/upload_main_file'
```

but in response I get the **422 Unprocessable Entity** error

What is the problem

Comment: Can you also post your route to the `upload_main_file` action?

Comment: you have to add 'CSRF-Token'. to your request: 
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line at the start of **upload_main_file** function fixed the problem

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```