# 422 when trying to send a put request from React using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rest, fetch

I am using React with Ruby on Rails, I am setting routes with React and in a component, within a route called scheduler I have the following:

```
  CreateMeeting = (data) => {
    const url = "meetings/create";
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
  }

  handleCreateMeeting = (data) =>{
      this.CreateMeeting(data);
  };

  SubmitMeeting = () =>{
    const newMeeting={
      scheduled: this.state.startDate,
      teacher_id: this.props.teacherId,
      user_id: this.props.current_user.id,
      length: 60
    }

    this.handleCreateMeeting(newMeeting);
  };
```

My react router looks like:

```
export default (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/teachers" exact component={Teachers} />
      <Route path="/meetings" exact component={Meetings} />
      <Route path="/teachers/:id" exact component={Teacher} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

The component in which I have the post request is within the route `/teachers/:id`

In the controller, my create action is:

```
    def create
      meeting = Meeting.create!(meeting_params)
      if teacher
        render json: meeting
      else
        render json: meeting.errors
      end
    end

    private

    def meeting_params
      params.permit(:user_id, :teacher_id, :scheduled, :length)
    end
```

And I have set the route as:

```
  post 'teachers/meetings/create', to: 'meetings#create'
```

I am getting the following error when the fetch executes.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/teachers/meetings/create 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
(anonymous) @ VM23:1
Scheduler._this.CreateMeeting @ Scheduler.jsx:24
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395854/422-unprocessable-entity-in-rails) (and several others like it) yet?

Comment: Hi, Sorry, that answer is actually solving the problem. It still triggers some other errors (500) and I thought it was not fixing it. That worked.